# After submit a message, a line-break occurs on textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to figure out, why in my chat app, everytime I send a message, the textarea puts a line-break instead of just focus on the textarea in the first line in order for me to send a new message.

Let me explain what happens in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wSFzpGnVkZg&feature=youtu.be) I recorded of my issue:

before send the first `hello` message, there is a `placeholder`: `Your message . . .`, then when I send `hello`, you should look at the textarea so you will clearly see that the placeholder isn't there anymore, and its because after sending the message, I have no idea why the textarea is putting a line-break, in the video, some seconds after I send the message, the placeholder appears again, is because I press the delete key/button in my keyboard in order to delete the line-break or the non-existence character in the text area.

All the HTML and CSS I have for that element is this

HTML

```
<div className="chat-form">
  <textarea className="input-form"
    placeholder="Your message..."
    ref="newMessage"
    onClick={this._onKeyDown}
    autofocus="true" ></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.chat-form {

  ::-webkit-input-placeholder,
  :-moz-placeholder,
  ::-moz-placeholder,
  :-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #ecf0f1;
    opacity: .4;
  }

  .input-form {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid rgba(192,192,192,0.3);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 2% 1% 6% 1%;
    position: relative;
    width: 85%;
  }

  textarea {
    resize: none;
  }
}
```

and the JavaScript part

```
  _addMessage () {
    let input = this.refs.newMessage.getDOMNode();
    this.props.onAddMessage(input.value);
    input.value = '';
    input.focus();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cancel the keydown event when they hit enter.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: I have it working now, awesome. But can you give an explanation about why this happens ?

Comment: Because you bind to the keydown event so it has not completed yet. So you clear the value and then the keypress event fires and adds the new line.